# c pointer with string

Tags: c, string, pointers

Trying to learn pointers better I wrote this code. The intention was to print one character of a string at a time in a for loop. Again trying to learn how to increment a pointer and then dereference the pointer.

```
char *string = "abcdef";
char *pointer = &string; 

for (int i =0; i < 4; i++)

{   
    printf("the next charater is %c\n", *pointer);
    pointer = (char *)pointer + sizeof(char);
}
```

want it to print:

the next charater is a

the next charater is b

the next charater is c

the next charater is d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char *pointer = &string;
```

should be

```
char *pointer = string;
```

`string` is a pointer variable that contains the address of your string literal. You want the address of the string literal, so you should simply copy the value in `string` - not take the address of the local pointer variable - your current code gives you a pointer to a pointer to a string.

Additionally, `pointer = (char *)pointer + sizeof(char);` doesn't require a cast, and it should not use `sizeof(char)`. When incrementing a variable of type `pointer to X`, incrementing it by one will increment it by `sizeof(X)` bytes - increment by one to point at the next `X`. Use `pointer += 1;` or `++pointer` instead.

Comment: cool so this works, could you please explain why.  I thought "&" was the address of operator. so why doesn't the *pointer contain the address of string in my sample code.  What is *pointer referencing in my sample code

Comment: @user700048: `string` points at "abcdef" - it already contains an address. What you do gives you the address of a variable which contains the address of "abcdef" - a pointer to a pointer to "abcdef"

Comment: @user700048: You're confused because you didn't just write `char *pointer = "abcdef"` in the first place: it's already an address. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print (or otherwise process) the whole string one char at a time, you may use the following idiom:

```
char *p = /* ... */;

while (p && *p) {
    printf("next char: %c\n", *p++);
}
```

The condition first tests whether p is NULL, i.e. if it is wise to dereference p at all. If p is not NULL, `*p` tests whether you already reached the end of the string, denoted by the `'\0'` character, which happens to be 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pointer to pointer to string then you can use like this:

```
char *string = "abcdef";
char **pointer = &string;
int i;
for (i =0; i < 4; i++)

{
    printf("the next charater is %c\n", **pointer);
    *pointer = *pointer + sizeof(char);
}
```